# How do you connect to multiple databases using knex.js?

Tags: knex.js

There is a process that takes data from one database and replicates it to another. They are on different db platforms. It is intended that knex.js be the middleware.
This works under 0.10.0

```
var first = require("knex")(...);
var second = require("knex").initialize(...);
```

but complains that initialize is deprecated. Can someone give an example of how to do this in the current version of knex.js?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why don't you use same syntax as for `first`? I guess that `.initialize` is just outdated(deprecated) version of just function call.

```
var first = require("knex")(firstConfig);
var second = require("knex")(secondConfig);

first.select('*').from('users');
second.select('*').from('table');
```

And you have 2 different builders (each with different config).

Comment: I was a bit confused because var knex = require('knex').knex; will give you an initialized state so I assumed it was holding the connection as a global. But I'll try it as you have shown and see how it goes.

Comment: It's just simple `var knex = require('knex')(your knex config here)` without `var knex = require('knex').knex`

Comment: How can I join users and table in your example?

Comment: @a.yushko have no idea to be honest. I guess you are looking for a cross-database queries. As far as I know Postgres can do that, but this topic goes beyond knex itself.